# Yellow on white badges are indistinct

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When placed over the paper-white background, the yellow is rather indistinct.

In particular, gold badges fade away to be practically invisible.

> [image]

Suggestions From A Design Ignoramus: Add some darker highlights or shadows - maybe to all the badges to make them consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think maybe our gold could simply be gold and carry the contrast it needs. the site doesn't use drop shadows/shading anywhere else. Thanks :) will adjust.